# Using Asset Field in a Template

Tags: assets

I'm confused about how to use an uploaded asset in a template (or rather why it isn't working).

1) I create an asset source and folder (Note: I did not add any fields).

2) I added this as a field in my entry fields called heroImage

3) I uploaded an asset to my single entry for the page.

4) I added this to the template

```
{% for asset in entry.heroImage %}
             {{ asset.url() }}
             XXXX
{% endfor %}
```

5) I also tried

```
    {% set assets = entry.heroImage %}
    {% if assets | length %}
      <h3>Some great assets</h3>
      {% for asset in assets %}
          {{ asset.url }}
      {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}
```

I can see the image on the entry page but the template wont render it.

What could be

Comment: Does the template generate anything on the front end for #4?

Comment: This was my mistake the issue was i was doing something else to change entry on the previous line...

    {% set entry = entry.otherThing.first() %}

Rookie...Can this be deleted?

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, surely you'll need to use an IMG tag?

```
{% for asset in assets %}
    <img src="{{ asset.getUrl }}" />
{% endfor %}
```